# Haddock for Cabal-installed modules?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I'm using GHC and have installed several packages via Cabal. One of the packages' web site says "go see the haddock documentation". The `haddock` command seems to only work on source files, and `cabal haddock` only seems to work in the top-level directory of a project with a `.cabal` build file. Is there a way to say "show me the haddock" for a module?

I'm longing for `pydoc -p 12345` which starts an HTTP server providing Python documentation based on what you have installed locally.

As a work-around, I extracted the source tarball from under `~/.cabal` and ran `cabal configure; cabal haddock` in the source directory, but that's kind of a pain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

edit your config file:

> ~/.cabal/config

there is a option to enable default install doc:

> documentation: True

to install doc of existing packages, use:

> cabal install xxx --reinstall

re-install docs from basic packages then the upper-level packages, so the "hyper-link" to other modules will be generated properly.

Answer (score 8):

The `--haddock` flag didn’t work for me.  However, replacing `--haddock` with `--enable-documentation` did:

```
cabal install $project --enable-documentation
```

Now, if they could allow the `--hyperlink-source` flag to zip through to haddock I’d be very happy.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/206). As a workaround you can configure your Apache installation (if you have one) to serve your doc directory using [this small PHP script](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/53531/focus=53572).

Comment: @Martjin: regarding that link, does hackage.haskell.org work for you? from here it looks like it's down for the last two days, and http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/hackage.haskell.org confirms..

Comment: Thanks, your notes in that post also led me to change my .cabal/config to generate docs by default.

Comment: Hackage should be back up now. :-) Yes, it was down for a while. People were asking about it in the Haskell café as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to generate local documentation with:

```
cabal install $project --haddock
```

Assuming you have Haddock installed.

Comment: Thanks - the hackage link in the other answer led me to the same flag. Then I updated my .cabal/config file to make that the default. Now (on OS X) I can say "open ~/.cabal/share/doc/$project-*/html/index.html" and the docs pop up in my browser. I've written a bash function to do that for a project name or print an error message if the index.html file doesn't exist.